# why is my matrix labels not showing the numbers from the list?

Tags: python, matrix, tkinter, label

With this code, the boxes are showing all 0's. I am not sure why it's not showing the sequence in the list. It should display "1" in the the position [0,0], "3" in the position [0,1], "2" in [0,2]... and so on until it fills all the 9 numbers in the 9 boxes.

```
import tkinter as tk

the_list = (1, 3, 2, 4, 12, 56, 7, 10, 19)
var_categories = {}

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("500x300")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        iterator = iter(the_list)

        for r in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                item = next(iterator)

                self.labelVariable = tk.IntVar()

                self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable, relief="ridge",width=8, height=3 )
                self.label.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='news')

                var_categories[item] = self.labelVariable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in the function `initUI`: when you create an `IntVar` you have to set its value, using its `set` method. Also, I guess that your `var_categories` dictionary should be indexed by its position on the matrix, not by the content of the matrix cell, am I right? Here is the modified function which offers the output you want:

```
def initUI(self):
    iterator = iter(the_list)
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            item = next(iterator)
            var_categories[r,c] = tk.IntVar()
            var_categories[r,c].set(item)
            self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=var_categories[r,c], relief="ridge",width=8, height=3)
            self.label.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='news')
```

Comment: thanks for the help on my doubts.  the intVar and set method I understand.  I was confused on how to reference the rows and  columns with a list.

Comment: for self study i was playing with your code. I used def initUI(self):
        
        for r in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                i=0
                for name in the_list:
                    new_list[r,c] = tk.IntVar()
                    new_list[r,c].set(name)
                    self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=new_list[r,c], relief="ridge",width=45, height=3) i am only getting the last digit.
                    self.label.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='news')
                    i += 1    and why  am I only getting the last digit on my grid? thanks